# Use same column twice in a table - PowerBI

Tags: sql, database, visualization, powerbi

I am currently working on a project on PowerBI. I have a database named `STATUS_PER_SCHEMA` which has a column named `RUN_TIME` which tells when the batch was run.  The database has values for RUN_TIME for each schema for the last 10 days. I want to use the same column twice in a single table. So basically I want the last and the first batch timing for each schema.

It should look something like this.

```
SCHEMA  LAST_BATCH_RUN  EARLIEST_BATCH_RUN
A   2018-05-21 12:00    2018-05-16 13:00
B   2018-05-21 12:00    2018-05-16 13:00
C   2018-05-21 12:00    2018-05-16 13:00
D   2018-05-21 12:00    2018-05-16 13:00
E   2018-05-21 12:00    2018-05-16 13:00
F   2018-05-21 12:00    2018-05-16 13:00
```

Comment: Why do you want to sort it twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
select
    SCHEMA, 
    max(RUN_TIME) as LAST_BATCH_RUN,
    min(RUN_TIME) as EARLIEST_BATCH_RUN
  from STATUS_PER_SCHEMA
  group by SCHEMA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stick the `SCEHMA` column in a matrix visual Rows section and create one measure for last run and one measure for the earliest run and drop those measures in the Values section.

```
LAST_BATCH_RUN = MAX(RUN_TIME)

EARLIEST_BATCH_RUN = MIN(RUN_TIME)
```